# Which statement in R

Tags: r

Given a plot of N against P, I'm trying to find out **what is the value of P**, **when N is 386** in R?

My data is obtained using this code in R:

```
N <- seq(from=100,to=2000,by=1)
P <- choose(N-100, 50) / choose(N, 60)
## Normalization of Ps:
sum(P)
P <- P / sum(P)
## Plot it:
plot(N, P, type = "l",las=1)
```

I'm using the following code with no success:

```
P[which(N) = 386]
```

Comment: In your data P ranges from 0 to 0.002; so no P is equal to 386.

Comment: Oh No, I'm asking WHAT IS P? when N is 386! N goes from 100 to 2000!!

Comment: See updated answer below:   `P[which(N == 386)]`

Comment: Purely programming-issue questions are [off topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here; given you've had multiple questions closed over this issue, I can only presume you must know this already. I would migrate this to stackoverflow but you're blocked from asking on SO. Don't post to another site (i.e. here) as a way of avoiding a block on the site where the question belongs -- resolve the issue that led to being blocked at the original site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, remember `which()` takes logical operator (i.e., `==`), you have provided `=` which is an assignment operator. If you have the plot, you must have data that generated it. Since you have not provided the data. I have created one myself.

```
# Set seed for reproducible example 
set.seed(42)     

# Create a dataframe of random numbers 
mydf <- data.frame(X=rnorm(45),Y=rnorm(45))

# For example set the value of 5th element to 386 as in your question
mydf$X[5] <- 386

# Print the fifth value of Y
print(mydf$Y[5])

# Use to find X where it is value and print equivalent value of Y
print(mydf$Y[which(mydf$X==386)])
```

**Update:**
With the newer set of data and questions you have provided:: Change the final statement to simply::

```
 P[which(N == 386)]
```

Comment: discipulus   thank you here is my data: 386 was just an example not related to my data. I will want the answer to be used in creating arrows.                                                                                                   N <- seq(from=100,to=2000,by=1)
P <- choose(N-100, 50) / choose(N, 60)

## Normalization of Ps to make the total area under the curve become 1:

sum(P)
P <- P / sum(P)
#P <- P / max(P)

## Plot it:

plot(N, P, type = "l",las=1)

Comment: Could you please update the question with data, not with a comment here?

Comment: sure, right away

Comment: I tweaked your 1st sentence to make your point clearer (+1), but I think I on the boundary of what is acceptable editing here. See if you're OK w/ it, & if not, roll it back w/ my apologies.

Comment: Thanks very much I was a = short of getting it, thanks a lot!

Comment: gung, this now looks very good. I appreciate your edit.

Comment: Just to add also the placement of the closing braces :-).